# Converting a scientific notation string to an integer

Tags: string, python-3.x, type-conversion, integer, scientific-notation

I have a question in Python 3.7. I am opening a text file (input.txt) and creating variables from various lines of the text file. For example my text file looks as follows:

```
Case1
P
1.00E+02
5.
```

I need to create variables so that:

```
title = "Case1"
area = "P"
distance = 100
factor = 5
```

So far this is what I have:

```
f = open('C:\\input.txt',"r")
title = f.readline().strip()
area = f.readline().strip()
distance = f.readline().strip()
factor = f.readline().strip().strip(".")
f.close
print(title)
print(area)
print(distance)
print(factor)
```

which results in:

```
Case1
P
1.00E+02
5
```

How do I get the distance variable to show up as 100 instead of 1.00E+02?

I found the link below thinking it would help, but wasn't able to solve my problem from there. This is a very small segment of my larger program that was simplified, but if it works here it will work for my needs. My program needs to open a generated text file and produce another text file, so the scientific notation number will change between 1.00E-06 and 1.00E+03. The generated text file needs to have these numbers as integers (i.e. between 0.000001 and 1000). Thanks for any help!

[Converting number in scientific notation to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32861429/converting-number-in-scientific-notation-to-int)

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Cant believe I forgot to add that; I am using python (version 3.7). I have updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you posted actually gives the answer, albeit in a roundabout way.
int() cannot parse strings that don't already represent integers.
But a scientific number is a float.

So, you need to cast it to float first to parse the string.

Try:

```
print(float(distance))
```

For numbers with more decimals (e.g your example of 1.00E-06), you can force float notation all the time.  Try:

```
print(format(float(distance), 'f'))
```

If you only want a certain number of decimals, try:

```
print(format(float(distance), '.2f'))
```

(for example)

Comment: Thanks that got me what I needed!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.