# Converting a 2.000000000000000000e+00 type number to int?

Tags: python-3.x, type-conversion

how can I convert this type of number:
2.000000000000000000e+00
to an int (valued 2)?

Thanks!

```
def read_labels_from_file(file_name):
    labels_file = open(file_name, "r")
    labels = []

    for line in labels_file:
        line_sepetated = line.split("\n")
        labels.append(int(line_sepetated[0]))
    return labels
```

I expected to have append the integer 2 to labels, but got:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2.000000000000000000e+00'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting number in scientific notation to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32861429/converting-number-in-scientific-notation-to-int)

Answer (score 0):

`2.000000000000000000e+00` is a valid floating point literal, so you can convert it to a `float` first before converting it to an `int`:

```
labels.append(int(float(line_sepetated[0])))
```